# 3000VA UPS Battery advice

Tags: ups

I am planning to upgrade my current UPS (BN1500M2, [here](https://www.apc.com/shop/us/en/products/P-BN1500M2)) to a bigger 3000VA so that it can handle power outage longer (at least an hour for 300W load). I found these two UPS (SMX3000RMLV2U, SRT3000XLA). Here is a comparison between the three:

https://www.apc.com/shop/us/en/tools/compare-products/30nbq/BN1500M2%7CSMX3000RMLV2U%7CSRT3000XLA/300

My first question is, what is the difference between "line interactive" with "double conversion online" topology. The two newer ones support sine waveform output. "SRT3000XLA" is 1000$ more expensive than "SMX3000RMLV2U". I also found [this](https://www.apc.com/us/en/faqs/FA230533/) page on generations of APC smart UPS.

[image]

Edit: The PowerChute software is showing the load ~300W when all equipment are attached. Each APC product has a page where at the end of the page, you can find "Run time for load" (one example [here](https://www.apc.com/shop/us/en/products/APC-Smart-UPS-SRT-3000VA-120V/P-SRT3000XLA)). I use 300 to get an estimate on the run time.

[image]

Edit: I found a very good [article](https://www.qpsolutions.net/2019/11/line-interactive-vs-double-conversion-ups-which-ones-best/) that explains the two topologies.

Is "SMX3000RMLV2U" suitable for my small home network? These are attached to my UPS:

- Two laptops
- One ultra-wide monitor
- One power-hungry desktop PC (Intel core i9-10980XE, Nvidia 3080 GPU)
- One sound-bar
- One NAS
- Two network switches
- Cable Modem
- Google Nest Mesh WiFi

Comment: what's a `small home network`?

Comment: Unless they spec Wh >300 capacity, it’s no good